# Embedded Python does not find some modules, (ctypes, ...)

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I am trying to run some embedded python code.
**while some of it works fine** some of the imports do no work.

```
// pseudo code
...
Py_SetPath("//path//to//python35.zip");
...
Py_Initialize();
PyEval_InitThreads();

char * s = "import ctypes\n\nctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()";
...
PyObject *main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject *main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);
...
PyObject * PyRes = PyRun_String(s, Py_file_input, main_dict, main_dict);
...
```

in fact, if all I do is call,

```
...
char * s = "import ctypes";
...
```

I get an error, ("ctypes" is not found).

But if I do ...

```
...
import time
t = time.ctime()
...
```

It works fine, so clearly some modules are loaded while others are not.

Any suggestions as to why "ctypes" would throw an error while others don't?

**Edit** : more code...

```
#include <python.h>

int main()
{
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Py_SetPath( L"path\\to\\python35.zip" );
  Py_Initialize();
  PyEval_InitThreads();
  PyThreadState *mainstate = PyThreadState_Get();
  PyEval_ReleaseLock();

  //
  // ...
  //
  // run the code.
  PyEval_AcquireLock();
  PyInterpreterState* mainInterpreterState = mainstate->interp;

  PyObject *main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
  PyObject *main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);
  Py_INCREF(main_module);

  PyObject *local_dic = PyDict_New();
  Py_XINCREF(local_dic);

  // we can now run our script
  const char* s = "import ctypes";
  PyObject * PyRes = PyRun_String(s, Py_file_input, main_dict, local_dic);
  PyObject* ex = PyErr_Occurred();
  if (NULL != ex)
  {
    //  didn't work, import error.
  }
  PyErr_Clear();

  PyDict_Clear(local_dic);
  Py_XDECREF(local_dic);
  Py_DECREF(main_module);

  PyThreadState_Swap(NULL);
  PyThreadState_Swap(mainstate);
  PyEval_ReleaseLock();

  //
  // ...
  //

  // close
  PyEval_AcquireLock();
  PyThreadState_Swap(mainstate);
  Py_Finalize();
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: How about you extract a minimal example for others to reproduce?

Comment: It is pretty much as I have it, stackoverflow does not allow more code to be added. Unless you can think of somewhere I could put it and link back to it here.

Comment: You misunderstand me and also you don't seem to know the site rules here. You are supposed to extract a minimal but complete example to post here. Your "pseudo code" is both superfluous and not enough, you need to provide code that allows anyone to reproduce your problem. This also helps avoid the usual cases of stupid questions, btw.

Comment: I understood exactly what you said, and I know the rules well enough, but you misunderstood my reply, (and probably my actual question). Anyway, I was able to add code.

Comment: I have an idea, but since there's no example code (Still! And *You* actually claim to know the site rules?) I can't test my theory. Why do you add "..." sections in your code but fail to add a simple `main()` in there? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: lol, I will add ``int main(){ ... }`` around the code. what is your "idea"?

Comment: There, I added ``int main(){ ... }`` around the code, and ``include "python.h"`` let me know what else you need to help you further. If you have any questions about it, feel free to ask. You can also go to python.org where they have a lot of sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is correct, the '*problem*' is with the embeddable. It is for release distribution and not debug, (and this is by design).

In the example code, the python dll looks for `_ctypes_d.pyd` in debug, but the redist only has `_ctypes.pyd` hence the reason it was failing to find the module.

The Python devs will write a blog about the usage of the embedded zip.

The code contain a project _ctypes.vcxproj that you can build if you want to build the _ctypes_d.pyd python module.

Please see [the bug report I created](http://bugs.python.org/issue26598) on python.org

Comment: A better explanation of what's going on can be found here: https://bugs.python.org/issue26598

Answer (score -1):

I had to fix the include, which should be `Python.h` instead of `python.h`, then I could compile and run your code to reproduce the problem. Now, the problem is caused by

```
Py_SetPath(L"path\\to\\python35.zip");
```

which messes up the path where Python searches additional modules, i.e. those that are not hard-compiled into the interpreter binary. That's also the reason why some `require` statements work and others don't. Those that work don't require a proper path because they don't need any additional files.

For reference, you can get the same behaviour from inside Python, too:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path = ['/path/to/some/archive.tar.gz']
>>> import time
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ctypes'
>>>
```

Comment: It's not a good question, for example because it lacks terseness. And yes, I verified my "claim", both via code and by reading the documentation. Why can't you? Are you incapable of locating the documentation? Does the code not produce the expected results after removing that line? Or do you only want to stomp your foot and hold your breath because someone dared to point out flaws in your "perfectly good question"?

Comment: Removing what line ``Py_SetPath(L"path\\to\\python35.zip");``?, why would I remove the one line that makes embedding possible. Clearly this shows you really don't understand the question and what the code actually does. As for the doc, you cannot quote anything because it is simply not there, (and it is not in the code either as you don't seem to understand what the function is actually for).

Comment: Seriously, that would be relevant and valuable info. Instead, you claim I don't understand what this is all about, all while the fixed code works here and you still haven't found the error. And btw, I did locate the documentation for `Py_SetPath()`, read it and I do understand what it is for, which brought me to my theory that this call is probably wrong. At best, it should point to a path where Python modules are installed, not to an archive. Also, it is not fundamental for embedding, as my attempts have shown me, although I can't rule out influences specific to your environment.

Comment: Sorry, the first part of you comment makes no sense. And, as for me trying to remove the code, there is no point in even attempting to do it. To embed Python I have to have that line of code. Removing it will work, of course, but it will not be embedded. Like I said earlier, if you had a question about C++/Python I would have been happy to help you with it. I think you should rather remove this 'answer' as it is completely wrong.

Comment: `Py_SetPath()` is not necessary for embedding, although it can be useful for it under certain circumstances. I have a vague feeling that you mean something different with "embedding" than what I and many others do.